# I want listView in asp.net by three column in browser in mobile one column

Tags: asp.net

I want **listView** in asp.net by three column in browser in mobile one column...

```html
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GroupItemCount="3" ItemPlaceholderID="itemsGoHere"
   GroupPlaceholderID="groupsGoHere">    
    <LayoutTemplate>    
    <table>    
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupsGoHere"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </table>    
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <GroupTemplate>
    <tr>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemsGoHere"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </tr>
    </GroupTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("fname")%>'/>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("lname") %>' />
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("age") %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Bootstrap is the solution for this. It is very easy to use when you create HTML manually like it's done in MVC using Razor. I am not sure how that would be used with ServerControls. you can go thru https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bootstrap and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/815916/Create-an-ASP-NET-Web-Forms-Application-using-Boot to start with.

Comment: May be this one too https://forums.asp.net/t/2080092.aspx?ListView+responsive+bootstrap